# How to remap gamepad axis?

Tags: gamepad

I am a Linux newbie and I need help remapping my gamepad, a twin gamepad actually (Gamebird JPD-ST03)

The problem is that for some reason axis 2 acts as axis 3 and vice versa... So when I move it upwards phisically in games it moves to the left...
I tried using jstest-gtk and I managed to remap them but it dosen't seem to affect any games at all...

It worked fine on Windows (using x360ce emulator) and also works fine on a game that runs using WINE (without the x360ce emulator)

Answer (score 1):

jstest-gtk only remaps the axis for the old /dev/input/js0 interface, which is however not used by any modern game. You can force it's use in SDL1 based games with:

```
 SDL_JOYSTICK_DEVICE=/dev/input/js0;export SDL_JOYSTICK_DEVICE
```

but since even SDL1 games are getting kind of old that will be of limited use as well.

For SDL2 based games there is the SDL_GAMECONTROLLERCONFIG environment variable which allows you to remap the joystick directly. If you are using Steam you can configure your controller in Big Picture Mode and it will automatically set that variable for you.

Comment: I am using Steam indeed. And yes, Big Picture mode did the trick! Thank you, sir!